# How can I add the following lines to my plist file?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, jailbreak, springboard

I have seen a lot of tutorials about adding to a plist file but I can't seem to correctly insert  nested tags into the plist file.
I want to add the following lines to my Info.plist file

```
<key>AppTag</key> <array>
     <string>hidden</string> </array>


NSMutableDictionary *plist = [[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:@"/Users/me/Desktop/Info2.plist"] mutableCopy];

  [plist setObject:@"AppTag" forKey:@"key"];
  [plist setObject:@"hidden" forKey:@"string"];

    [plist writeToFile:@"/Users/me/Desktop/Info2.plist" atomically:YES];
    [plist release];
```

Comment: It's unclear what you want to add and what you're getting instead.

Comment: I edited my question.See it again

Comment: are getting some error while executing this code? it seems to be ok, by the way, the file `@"/Users/me/Desktop/Info2.plist"` exists?, if not your `plist` variable will be `null` and them *nothing will happen*

Comment: I am not getting any error.I am getting the wrong output.and I am not getting nested tags.I just want to know how to add these tags to my plist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set an array of strings as the object for key `@"AppTag"`, like so:

```
NSArray *strings = @[@"hidden"];
plist[@"AppTag"] = strings;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is add `strings` to your `array`, and then the `array` to the `dictionary` of the file. In the following example, I'm adding some words and their definitions to a file called `WordList.plist`:

```
NSArray *values = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:word.name, word.definition, nil];
NSArray *keys = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: NAME_KEY, DEFINITION_KEY, nil];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithObjects:values forKeys:keys];
[wordsListArray addObject:dict];

NSString *destinationPath = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,
 NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
destinationPath = [destinationPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"WordList.plist"];
[wordsListArray writeToFile:destinationPath atomically:YES];
```

I hope this helps.

Also, I think this is the part that's not working fine: `@"/Users/me/Desktop/Info2.plist"`

Try NSLogging.

Comment: If you see my requirements.The string tag must be nested in the array tag.I just wanna know how I can achieve this? I want to add my given xml to an already existing info.plist file but its very confusiong.Tell me how do I achieve that?

Comment: What you're doing is right for doing the nested tags, but you cannot save a file outside the `Documents` folder of your app, so you can't save the file on Desktop. Try using the second part of my code to save it in that folder.

Comment: its a jailbroken device and I can save anywhere I want :)

Comment: Hmm... Then try NSLog to see what you get.

Answer (score 1):

You can try following code

```
-(NSString *) datafilepath{



NSArray *path=NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documents=[path objectAtIndex:0];
return [documents stringByAppendingFormat:@"/Info2.plist"]; // you can change the path to desktop
}
```

Under ViewDidLoad or any method

```
NSString *filepath3=[self datafilepath];
if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager]fileExistsAtPath:filepath3]) {
    pricedict=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithContentsOfFile:filepath3];
}

[pricedict setObject:@"AppTag" forKey:@"key"];
[pricedict setObject:@"hidden" forKey:@"string"];

[pricedict writeToFile:pngfilepath atomically:YES];
```

Hope this helps.. Happy coding 